Automatically creating and updating the monitoring of CPU and other metrics for the SageMaker pipeline
What I want to achieve:

When a pipeline is created, automatically create alarms for metrics associated with the pipeline. If CPU usage or other metrics exceed the configured threshold, trigger an alert.
When the pipeline is updated, a new pipeline is expected to be created separately from the old one. In that case, the old pipeline's associated metrics and alarms should be automatically deleted, and new monitoring resources should be created for the updated pipeline.

How can the above be achieved?
１．I tried creating alarms with boto3, but as you know, when a SageMaker pipeline is updated, the ID in the metrics namespace changes. As a result, new alarms need to be created, making it very inefficient to manage a large number of unnecessary resources.
２．It is possible to achieve my goal by creating SageMaker pipelines and alarms simultaneously with CloudFormation using boto3, managing them as a stack. However, CloudFormation management is not that simple, and I am looking for a more straightforward solution.
３．Is there a way to pre-configure alerts and later associate them with the pipeline?
